# Subtract time worked with text in excel

Tags: excel-formula, subtraction

I have a monthly timesheet with start, end, break time and holiday. I need to see how many hours per week , but Holiday is an text (OFF) and not sure how to correct the formula.

Example:
Start - Finish - Break = Hours worked
8:30     12:00     0:30    3h  /I have used =(finish-start-break)*24
Off       Off       Off   #VALUE!

How it's the simple way to correct this error #VALUE! ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Very hard to tell without more info. I get 3 hours not 3.5 hours.

Comment: Hi Mark, you are right. I have tipped the wrong value, just edited, Thank you!  But my issue is when they are OFF so the formula doesn't work.